# Find Latest CreatedDate from a list of sObjects

Tags: apex, visualforce, create-records, sobjectfield

I have a sObject List AttachList

```
        Boolean retVal = false; 
        DateTime AttachCreatedDate = '';
        ID attachId = '';

        for(AttachDetails__c attachDetail : AttachList) {
            if(attachDetail .CreatedDate>AttachCreatedDate){
                AttachCreatedDate =attachDetail .CreatedDate;
                attachId =attachDetail .ID;
            }               
        }
```

What I am trying to do here is to find the id of the record having the latest createddate. But the AttachCreatedDate  field is not taking null as the initial value. can anyone offer me suggestions as to how to fix this. Is there any alternative way to find the ID of the Latest Created record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might rename `attacheCreatedDate` to `mostRecent`. Regardless, the simplest change is probably to instantiate it to the first value in the list:

```
Datetime mostRecent = attachList[0].CreatedDate;
```

Not sure how you ever got this line to compile, but it should replace:

```
Datetime AttachCreatedDate = '';
```

Comment: `Id attachId = ''` is also invalid (compiles but will crash at the point of assignment).

Comment: I should have figured that out. Thanks @Adrian. It was super helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind burning a query, for example, when it's just once per transaction on a Visualforce page, you can just ask the database:

```
Id attachId = [SELECT Id FROM AttachDetails__c WHERE Id IN :attachList ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1].Id;
```

Do make sure that attachList is not empty first, or you'll get a no-rows-for-assignment exception.

Alternatively, you could also choose to compare to null first:

```
for(AttachDetails__c attachDetail : AttachList) {
  if(attachCreatedDate==null || attachDetail.CreatedDate>AttachCreatedDate) {
    AttachCreatedDate =attachDetail.CreatedDate;
    attachId =attachDetail.ID;
  }
}
```

But this is slightly less efficient than setting the attachCreatedDate variable to some already known value.